# How to generate Folium map using GeoDataFrame?

Tags: python, json, geospatial, geopandas, folium

I have created a geoDataFrame using, and would like to create a Folium Map, plotting the population eat for each country. Do I have to create the Json file, or I can directly use the geoDataFrame file?

```
import folium
import fiona
import geopandas as gpd

world = fiona.open(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features([feature for feature in world])
world = world[(world.pop_est > 0) & (world.name != "Antarctica")]
```

I used folium.map and geojson function, but it failed to create correct JSON files.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note: you can change the two first lines (to create the dataframe) with `world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent releases of folium, you don't need to convert the GeoDataFrame to geojson, but you can pass it directly. Connecting the population column to color the polygons is still somewhat tricky to get correct:

```
m = folium.Map()
m.choropleth(world, data=world, key_on='feature.properties.name',
             columns=['name', 'pop_est'], fill_color='YlOrBr')
m
```

Comment: Hi @joris, do you know what is the current state of this method? The docstring mentions : "This method may be deleted after a year from now (Nov 2018)"

Answer (score 2):

The `m.cholopleth()` code in @joris's answer is now deprecated. The following code produces the same result using the new `folium.Chloropleth()` function:

```
m = folium.Map()
folium.Choropleth(world, data=world, 
                  key_on='feature.properties.name',
                  columns=['name', 'pop_est'], 
                  fill_color='YlOrBr').add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```